# How to split a numpy array multiple times with multiple indices?

Tags: python, numpy, split

I want to split at array multiple times at various indices.

Example:

```
y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I want to split this array at indices 2, 4, 7 to generate the following result:

```
res = [[[0, 1], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]],
       [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]],
       [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]]
```

I tried using numpy.split but it seems to only be able to split once, not multiple times to generate the result matrix. Is there a way to do this using numpy's vectorized operations without using loops?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a vectorized operator. The result itself is not a typical matrix since it is not rectangular. Alternatively, you can simply use list comprehension.

```py
y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

split_at = [2, 4, 7]
output = [[y[:x], y[x:]] for x in split_at]
print(output) # [[[0, 1], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]], [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]], [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]]
```